# How to use Flush Command in MySQL Effectively?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

We are facing a problem, our DB instance MySQL 8.0 (Production environment) is continuously showing an alert that number of open tables is equal to table_open_cache value. The number of open tables is increased more than 43,200 in 24 hour observation period which makes total count of open tables equals to 2845063.

Please help me how to reduce this, If I go for Flush tables command with read only or with read lock will it cause any data loss or performance issues. I have to implement this to my production Database, Is it a good practice to use Flush tables manually once a day.

Posted a question regarding MySQL DB instance open tables, need to know how to reduce the same by any method. Is it a good practice to use Flush tables manually once a day.

I am attaching an image for reference :-

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fghEI.jpg)

Comment: So you mean your `table` is over `2million` or `rows in the table`? Why having million `table`?

Comment: What is the exact metric name?  "open tables" is one thing' "opened tables" is another.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%open%'; SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'Uptime';`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed yes we do contains more than 2 million of data in a table

Comment: @RickJames metric name is table_open_cache

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%open%:                                                            
 have_openssl;YES
innodb_open_files;4000
open_files_limit;4194304
table_open_cache;4000
table_open_cache_instances;16  @RickJames

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%':                                                                  Com_ha_open;0
Com_show_open_tables;6
Innodb_num_open_files;4000
Open_files;5
Open_streams;0
Open_table_definitions;2000
Open_tables;4000
Opened_files;4125
Opened_table_definitions;1063849
Opened_tables;5071137
Slave_open_temp_tables;0
Table_open_cache_hits;244293222
Table_open_cache_misses;4697137
Table_open_cache_overflows;4608528    @RickJames

Comment: And Uptime?  That is needed for getting "per second", which is much more meaningful than those big numbers.

Comment: @AkhilUmap - It is quite common to have any "cache" full.  I can see from the "misses" that entries are occasionally bumped out to make room for a newly opened table.

Answer (score 0):

Misses/Hits is about 2% -- reasonable.

Apparently that screenshot should be talking about "opened" tables, not "open" tables.  Only 4K are currently "open", limited by `table_open_cache`.

The image shows 43.2K vs 2.8M -- it is unclear what each means.  43.2K/24h is exactly 1 per 2 seconds.  This is suspect.

2.8M openings of tables in 24 hours is high, but not necessarily "bad.  (It's about the 95th percentile.)

Suggest increasing `table_open_cache` to 8000.  What activity is going on?  Perhaps you are opening a connection, performing a single operation (which involves opening one or more tables), then disconnecting?  Can you cut back on the rapidity of creating connections?

Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Connection';`  50 per second is "high".

I await seeing `Opened_tables` and `Uptime` fetched *at the 'same' time*.

No, I don't think `FLUSH` is the answer.